# Mysql too many connection error

Tags: mysql, mysql-connect

I think something wrong with this graph.. but i don't know what error is this..

[image]

I tried to increase max connection from 150 to 300, i still got the same error..

Any idea what happenned?

Please help.. thx

Comment: The question is not clear, but as roughly speaking, if there is a calling application that is using the database and opening connections, there might be a chance that these connections are not closed well

Comment: Based on the graph, the process way bigger than its connection, i don't know what cause that,,,

Comment: There is an application access this mysq server and never get error too many connection until today it's show up error..

Comment: @KAD check this KAD.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlLSh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact you did not specified what type of applications are querying your server, and because every server under specific uses needs specific setup, I cannot say you: set this and that value here and there.

Try analyzing what application does.
Try setting in runtime `interactive_timeout` and `wait_timeout` on a lower value. If queries from apps you know are not so complex, try lowering the value of `thread_stack`.

Also, try to take a look at your server hard disk space. Sometimes and under certain conditions this error is thrown when hard disk space is little.

Sometimes, if applications are exposed to the www, search engine bots at work can consume resources. You should tune your robots.txt Crawl-delay value according to [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my disk was full. Since it was a VM I was able to extend the hard drive and things went back to normal.